# What is more efficient? Do sql query inside php code or post data to the php code?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using Wordpress for this site. I have order data from users that is retrieved by get-order.php.

So on the order page, the data is retrieved by requiring the get-order.php file. They can upload a file on this page. When they upload the file and submit, I use ajax to send the file to upload-file.php for validation and database changes.

I am wondering if it would be more efficient to add the already received data on the order page to the data set sent by ajax, or requiring the get-order.php in the upload-file.php. I am guessing posting is more efficient since you won't have to run the query again, just making sure.

Comment: Thanks Samosa! I was thinking about session as well but I am not familiar with it. Still somewhat new to everything. I will look into it.

Comment: This is not the question you should be asking.  Build what makes sense for the maintainability and usability of your application.  Your question of efficiency ignores all the things that actually make your application efficient.

Comment: The reason I am asking is because of how slow the website is working with these uploads. It could be plugins or server, but I wanted to double check if this was an alright way of getting data to mark the includes off of the list.

Comment: I updated my answer to show a simple usage of session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about how sensitive "order data" is but I wouldn't trust the posted data since it can be easily manipulated.

Either get the data again by including "get-order.php" or put the order data in $_SESSION which can be accessed all across the script.

I would personally prefer session route.

Using session in php is very easy :-

```
session_start(); //Initializes the session
$order_data = get_data(); //function or method that gets the order data
$_SESSION['order_data'] = $order_data;

//In some other place
$order_data = $_SESSION['order_data'];
```